# What is the difference between sharedPreferences.getBoolean() and findPreference(KEY).isChecked()

Tags: android, sharedpreferences

I have a `PreferenceFragment` having a `SwitchPreference`. The Switch is currently turned on, and I want to turn it off (false) in `onResume()`. However, I notice a strange result: after writing the preference to be false, I get different results when using `findPreference(KEY)).isChecked())` and using `sharedPreferences.getBoolean(KEY, defaultValue))`

```
public class SettingsFragment extends PreferenceFragment {
    private static final String KEY = "pref_enable";
    ....

    @Override
    public void onResume() {
        super.onResume();
        SharedPreferences sharedPreferences = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(getActivity());

        //Log the current value of SwitchPreferences, should be true
        Log.d(TAG, "before by findPref: " + ((SwitchPreference) findPreference(KEY)).isChecked());
        Log.d(TAG, "before by sharedPref: " + sharedPreferences.getBoolean(KEY, true));

        sharedPreferences.edit().putBoolean(KEY, false).apply();

        //Log the value of SwitchPreferences after writing false, should be false
        //this still prints true (WRONG)
        Log.d(TAG, "after by findPref: " + ((SwitchPreference) findPreference(KEY)).isChecked());
        //this prints false (as expected)
        Log.d(TAG, "after by sharedPref: " + sharedPreferences.getBoolean(KEY, true));
    }
    ....
}
```

And the output is:

```
before by findPref: true
before by sharedPref: true
after by findPref: true
after by sharedPref: false
```

Then I open my xml settings in the `/data/data/packagename/shared_prefs` folder to check, the result is now false (as expected). After that I kill the app by pressing Back and then open it again, then the log is now as expected (all false because we have set the switch to false before)

```
before by findPref: false
before by sharedPref: false
after by findPref: false
after by sharedPref: false
```

Which means that this statement `((SwitchPreference) findPreference(KEY)).isChecked()` right after writing false to the Switch produces wrong result. Why is that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
((SwitchPreference) findPreference(KEY)).isChecked()
```

This tells if the checkbox preference (shown on screen) is checked or not. It only depicts the state of checkbox which may be used for further programming purposes.

---

```
sharedPreferences.getBoolean(KEY, true)
```

This *returns* what is stored in shared preference for the given key (or return default if not available). It can be used separately regardless of your preference views and is used to store values.

---

However, In general, your preference views are given a **keyId** that is the same as used to store its value in default shared preference and when ever you change its state, the value is updated immediately in the xml.

Comment: but suppose that I want to make the preference to be false and unchecked programmatically. What I understand from your answer is that I cannot update the xml by `sharedPreferences.edit().putBoolean(KEY, false).apply();` and expect the preference view to be unchecked, but instead I should use `((SwitchPreference) findPreference(KEY)).setChecked(false);` and then my xml file will be updated immediately. Is that right?

Comment: preferences are directly connected to its keyId in xml. So whenever a change is occurred, that change is reflected in xml too. The thing is, you shouldn't get confused by overriding the value manually.

Comment: but what I want is to make the preference to be unchecked and false programmatically (not by touching the screen). I have successfully done it by `setChecked(false)` and that is exactly what I want. I understand the first half of your answer, but the part from "Moreover, the reason..." onwards does not answer my question because setting it to false programmatically is what I want, it's not because I am confusing. So I think you should remove that part and I will mark your answer as my answer.

Answer (score 0):

[`apply` is asynchronous](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/SharedPreferences.Editor.html#apply()).

and if u using `PreferenceFragment`, there is no need to save value by yourself.
It's treated by framework automatically, i think.